# Are "could" and "would be able to" always interchangeable?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-choice

Example sentence:

> At first, I thought of writing a note. But then I figured that with a recording, you **could/would be able to** lie down and close your eyes.

Maybe I'm wrong but *could* sounds more "pushy" than *would be able to.* But again, maybe I'm wrong and they mean exactly the same?

Comment: **She could sing beautifully** doesn't (always) mean the same thing as **She would be able to sing beautifully.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word ***could*** indicates **possibility**, and the phrase **to be able to do something** means to have the **power and skill to do something**.

**To me this sounds as if this person would only be able to lie down and close her eyes if she listened to your recording, your recording would give this person the power to do it.**

> At first, I thought of writing a note. But then I figured that with a
>   recording, you would **be able to** lie down and close your eyes.

**Now, this sounds a little different it sounds that with a recorded message this person would have the option, the possibility to lie down, relax, close their eyes and listen to your recording.**

> At first, I thought of writing a note. But then I figured that with a
>   recording, you could lie down and close your eyes.